# How To Access Items in an Editable Area?

Tags: xpages

I would like access a view in an Editable Area, with SSJS

I've tried somthing like this

```
var callback1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspCallback = getComponent("callback1");
print(callback1.getChildren().get(0).getValue())
```

but the only result was the Object ID. Is there a chance to get the whole object?

I think it is easy but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: are you trying to get access to the component xp:viewpanel?

Comment: Really what do you want? If you are trying to get the viewpanel's all  value, then the mentioned code returns first entry's first column value. And getComponent("callback1") is the container of whole object.

Comment: My idea was to insert a View in the Editable area and read the values of this in my Custom control. I thought that this could be easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of an editable area aren't children, they're facets:

```
callback1.getFacet("facetName")
```

Replace facetName with whatever you named the facet when you defined the editable area. If the above expression returns anything other than null, then the editable area has content.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik a callback point doesn't have children. The comtrols become children of the control containing the callback. You could try getParent (not sure if that works on Callbacks) and look from there. If a control only has one callback, thrn children of its parent is clear. Failing all this you can wrap the callback into a panel

Comment: My idea was to insert a View in the Editable area and read the values of this in my Custom control. I thought that this could be easy...

Comment: Isn't that a little inside out? You would pass a view name or view object as a parameter to your control.

Comment: Yes a little bit. I only had the idea to build an custom control drag an drop somthing like a view in an editable area and for example change the format of a column, insert a Pager or something else